# Cannot install AWS toolkit for eclipse.How to fix these errors?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install AWS toolkit for eclipse in Eclipse Helios. I cannot install it as I am getting the following errors. How to fix this?

```
       Missing requirement: IdentityManagement 1.0.0.v201402141427 (com.amazonaws.eclipse.identitymanagement 1.0.0.v201402141427) requires 'bundle com.amazonaws.eclipse.ec2 1.1.0' but it could not be found
       Cannot satisfy dependency:
       From: AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core 2.0.1.v201402141427  (com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.feature.feature.group 2.0.1.v201402141427)
       To: com.amazonaws.eclipse.identitymanagement [1.0.0.v201402141427]
```

Comment: Is that all there is in the error log? Are there any more unsatisfied dependencies?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the answer for my question. First go to  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios and install Database development. Then go to  http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse and installAmazon EC2 Management. And lastly install the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse.

Comment: this worked for me, just as the steps said. Upon installing EC2 Management and launching Eclipse, a prompt will appear for entering the Access Key and Secret

Comment: I installed the latest version of the Toolkit today (AWSSDK.2.3.11) onto Eclipse Kepler and things seem slightly improved: the installer gave a list of components to install. I tried selecting just the SDK and got the error mentioned above. Adding the EC2 Management component fixed it. Thanks for the hint.